# Is MPI_Allgather my code bottleneck, and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, mpi

I have a program whose purpose is to add specific data to one main array.  A random number test `passesTest(randomNumber)` is performed millions of times each second, and very occasionally the test is passed and the random number is pushed onto the end of the array.  So most of the time the array is just sitting there while computations are going on.

I decided to parallelize this procedure with MPI, since I figured 1000 processors performing the random number test would be a big speed-up, and as memory writes are very infrequent, MPI should be well-suited to the job.  Much to my dismay, my program is fastest with `mpirun -np 1` and gets significantly slower with each process that I add.

At the end of my `while` loop that contains `passesTest(randomNumber)`, I have `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Allgather()` to gather a flag from each process that indicates whether there is a new random number that needs pushing onto the array.  If any of the flags is `true` then I perform another `Allgather()` to actually collect this data and push it onto each process' local copy of the array.  Again, this second `Allgather()` is performed very infrequently because the test is rarely passed.

So I'm guessing that my bottleneck is collecting all the flags from each MPI process to see if there is new data.  The test of each random number is fast to perform, so I assume that what was billions of while loops per second is now significantly reduced because of the overhead of collecting data from multiple processes.  Is this a good guess?  I'm new to MPI so I don't know what kind of timescale is involved with `Allgather()`.

If this is the reason, then how can I only "interact" with the other processes when a test is passed?  This is really all I want to do.  In other words, if a random number passes a test, then send a message out to all the other processes to halt what they're doing and add that number onto their array.

Comment: So since presumably the order in which you push data onto the array doesn't matter and you hopefully don't rely on the new data in the actual test, why are you doing all the unnecessary communication? Compute all the stuff locally and push large chunks of data back at the end (or regularly every few 100 million of iterations or whatever).

Comment: Well, I actually do rely on the new data in the actual test :(  I simplified the whole thing a bit for this question.

Comment: Removing necessary dependencies from a question about optimizations may not actually be very useful I fear. You'll have to describe the exact form of the data dependency before we can say anything.

Comment: I would have used `MPI_Allreduce` with `MPI_LOR` to get the global boolean flag. Nevertheless, I don't think anyone here is able to get performance data about your code out of thin air. There are plethora of MPI profiling tools like TAU, mpiP, VampirTrace/Vampir, Intel TAC, Scalasca, and so on - just use them and see for yourself if indeed the gather-to-all operation is a bottleneck (I would recommend Vampir, if you or your institution happen(s) to be in possession of a license for it).

Comment: How are you generating those random numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

First I strongly second Voo's and Hristo Iliev's comments.

Starting with an `MPI_Allreduce` to check for passes is clearly faster - it needs to transfer much less data. However Allreduce still needs > `2 * log2(n) * latency`. For 1000 processes it may be around 100s of microseconds depending on your system. If you have millions of tests per second, meaning each test takes only 100s of nanoseconds, it becomes quite clear that a collective operation after each test will indeed kill your performance - no matter how optimal each individual communication step is designed.

Now without knowing about the dependency it is difficult to suggest fundamental improvements. You could think about speculatively executing a number of iterations assuming no hit, discarding the invalid ones after you figure out there is a hit.

Further than that I would suggest `MPI_Allreduce` with `MAX` to determine the highest random number that needs to be added. Repeat that until all are added. This obviously only works well if there are usually very few additions.